# Prove that unit disk/~ is homeomorphic to $S^2$

Tags: general-topology

I find this example in Topology 2nd ed. by James Munkres P.139 Example 4

Let $X = \{x \times y \mid x^2+y^2\leq1\}$, $X^*$ be the partition of X consisting of all the one-point sets $\{x \times y \}$ for which $ x^2+y^2< 1 $ along with the set $S^1=\{\{x \times y\}\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$

Show that $X^*$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$ where $S^2=\{(x,y,z) \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$

$X^*$ just likes gluing the boundary together to form a sphere.So I identify $\{0 \times 0\}$ to $(0,0,-1)$, which means I match the centre to the south pole. Then I divide the disc into two parts: For $x^2+y^2=r^2$ where $r<0.5$, I map $(x,y)$ maps into $(\alpha x,\alpha y, r)$ where $\alpha ^2 = \frac{1-r^2}{r^2}$
. It means I map the inner ball into southern hemisphere. I do the similar thing for the remaining annulus. Finally, I map the $S^1$ into the north pole$=(0,0,1)$

Am I doing it right?

Thank you!

Comment: There is something incorrect in the title or body of this question. I think you meant the closed unit disk, modulo its boundary, as in:$ D^2:=\{x \times y \mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$. Then, consider the following equivalence: $x \sim y$ if and only if $x,y \in \partial D^2$ (note that the boundary is just $S^1$.) Show that the resulting set with the quotient topology is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: I've edited the title to make it correct.

Comment: A continuous bijection from a compact space into a Hausdroff space is automatically a homeomorphism. The space $X^*$ is compact (continuous image of the compact $D^2$ via the (continuous) projection. Find a surjective continuous function from $D^2$ to $S^2$ that passes to the quotient as a bijection and you're done.